# Oracle sql to find the next monday from the stop time in the query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-bi

If the Start_time  is 01/06/2023 and 01/19/2023 - Stop_Time in the BELOW  query,

```
select distinct start_time, stop_time
hwm_tm_rec_grp_sum
and sysdate between start_time and stop_time
```

I need to create another query that returns the 01/23/2023  which will be the next monday from the stop_time in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct start_time, stop_time, next_day(stop_time,'MONDAY')
...etc...
```

Comment: I tried next_Day but it is giving me an ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
error

Comment: Use a day of the week in the date language of your session, Montag, Lunes, Poniedziałek. Or `alter session set nls_date_language=English` and Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRUNC(date_value, 'IW')` to truncate to midnight Monday of that week and then add 7 days:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       start_time,
       stop_time,
       TRUNC(stop_time, 'IW') + 7 AS next_monday
...
```

This will work regardless of the session language.